# Matlab Substitute values in a Symbolic matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Creating

```
A = sym('A', [2 2])
B = sym('B', [2,1])
```

produces:

```
A =
    [ A1_1, A1_2]
    [ A2_1, A2_2]
```

and

```
B = 
    B1
    B2
```

Taking `x = A\B` gives

```
x = 
    -(A1_2*B2 - A2_2*B1)/(A1_1*A2_2 - A1_2*A2_1)
     (A1_1*B2 - A2_1*B1)/(A1_1*A2_2 - A1_2*A2_1)
```

I pull out the numerator using `numden` and I get

```
n(1) = -(A1_2*B2 - A2_2*B1)
```

to substitute the values in `n(1)`, I have to do

```
A1_2 = 1, A2_2 = 3, B1 = 4, B2 = 6
```

then using `subs(n(1))` I get answer as `6`. This is just a simple example as to how I do this for small scale matrices.
What I want to learn is for a huge matrix, is there a way, I can equate the symbols of the `A` matrix with numeric values using some loop and comparing it with other numeric Matrix say `N` other than the way I just showed.
My work requires huge matrices, and it is not as simple as taking `x = A\B`, for direct numeric matrices so please don't give that as solution.

Comment: This is fundamentally different than what you asked before.  Deleting my answer.

Comment: So you want the general symbolic solution for "huge" (what is huge?) linear systems and then you want to plug in numeric values into these? Why? This will *not* be faster. Do you think that it will be more accurate for your particular systems? Or are you not solving linear systems at all and this is just an example –if so ask the specific question you're actually interested in so that we can be helpful. I don't see why @rayeng's original answer isn't valid for your modified question so you need to explain what you want better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer,

For any numeric`X` and `Y` in the order of symbolic`A` and `B`.

for i=1:2

```
for j = 1:2
   eval(sprintf('A%d_%d=X(%d,%d)', i,j,i,j));
   eval(sprintf('B%d=Y(%d)', i,i));
end
```

end

then afterwards, using `subs(n)` and `subs(d)` I get the required answers.

Comment: Yuck at `eval`. -1. Sorry. There are better ways to doing this than using `eval`. Don't take it personally. I down vote any solutions that use `eval` when it isn't required.

Comment: I'll be glad if you show me other way of doing it!! And what do you mean it's not required?? this is the way, I figured it out!!

Comment: @rayryeng, look now I don't appreciate you down voting my solution,  cause if you really do know other better ways of doing it then you better show, rather than just saying and disappearing!!

Comment: I've been away. Sorry removing the vote. It's your answer so if it worked, OK! Btw mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I'll be glad if you show me how to do it without `eval`.