# write a set of equation from a csv file by matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using MATLAB. I want to read a csv file and write a linear equation for each line after that i want to get a matrix for scaler. I try a lot of way for example i try to determine a set of sym variables but it seems mockery! can someone help me.

**update:**

i want to write following equations automatically with loop

```
hA = 800;
y= csvread('adjs.csv');
y = y(:,3);
syms hB hC hD hE;
[A, y] = equationsToMatrix(...
hB - hA ==y(1),...
hC - hB ==y(2),...
hA - hC ==y(3),...
hD - hB ==y(4),...
hE - hD ==y(5),...
hC - hE ==y(6),...
hA - hE ==y(7),...
hD - hC ==y(8),...
hB, hC, hD, hE);
```

Comment: What did u try, what didnt wotk out?

Comment: I try to determine a set of sym variable by a 'for' loop for each line but it didn't work

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: post example code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help.I found what function can help me. it was sym('H',1 8). [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27659889/matlab-substitute-values-in-a-symbolic-matrix) explain that. it generates a matrix of symbolic expresions.